# Delete Service fabric Service via ARM template

Tags: azure-service-fabric, azure-rm-template

I have an application, that has 3 services (Service 1 to 3) and I deploy these services via ARM templates to different clusters. Service 3 now needs to be removed. Now, when I change my application manifest to just remove that service and deploy my ARM templates, Service Fabric deployment fails with the following error:

```json
{
  "ClassName": "System.Fabric.FabricException",
  "Message": "Services must be explicitly deleted before removing their Service Types ......"
}
```

Searching on the internet, I see that the service needs to be removed using the [Remove-ServiceFabricService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicefabric/remove-servicefabricservice?view=azureservicefabricps) cmdlet.

I wanted to check if that is the only option to delete services OR is there any other way using ARM templates to remove SF services or may be a way to disable the above check since the deletion is intentional.

Comment: You can use deployment scrips to run delete command in PowerShell https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-script-template#use-inline-scripts

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the [documentation says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/how-to-managed-cluster-app-deployment-template#delete-application-resources) you have to use Powershell to remove them:

> To delete an application that was deployed by using the application
> resource model in Resource Manager:
>
> Use the Get-AzResource cmdlet to get the resource ID for the
> application:
>
> `Get-AzResource  -Name <String> | f1`
>
> Use the Remove-AzResource cmdlet to delete the application resources:
>
> `Remove-AzResource  -ResourceId <String> [-Force] [-ApiVersion <String>]`